# Modular code in meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to write fully object oriented code in Meteor by using classes and objects. So, what is the best way to write object oriented code in Meteor (both client and server)?

Comment: es6 is the way to go

Comment: This is way too broad and opinionated a question for SO however you might find [this](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/models) interesting. You'll get the answer by reading expert blog posts.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also suggest the best approach for performing unit testing in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

This article shows how to make your Meteor project es6:
http://info.meteor.com/blog/es2015-get-started

If you use es6 methodology, it should all be object orientated.

Have you read the tutorials page on testing?
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/testing

and here is a more in-depth guide:
https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html

Comment: Linking out to tutorials isn't a good answer. Please use the question area to explain the important parts so the answer can live on beyond the life of that link.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  What did you mean by 'the question area'?

Comment: Sorry that should have said answer area.